# Math.exp() for bigInt?

Tags: javascript, math, biginteger

How can I do the equivalent of [`Math.exp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/exp), i.e. `e ^ argument` for [BigInt](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)?

I would try `bigInt(Math.E).pow(2000)` or similar but bigInt only handles ints, not floats.

Comment: Convert to BigDecimal, do the exponentiation, and then convert back?

Comment: Thanks @OliverCharlesworth. But assuming https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js, converting using `new big(Math.E)` fails with `BigDecimal(): Not a number: 2.718281828459045`

Comment: Ah, for a start, I misread this as Java, not JavaScript!  So I'm probably not qualified to comment on the specifics of that library... ;)

Comment: Do you realize that if `x` is large enough to require a BitInt, then `exp(x)` will almost surely overflow whatever datatype it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd actually misunderstood my own question - although the value I wanted to run exp on was calculated using BigInts, it was still only a few digits.

`Math.exp()` in fact does what I want.